# Can a MySQL field store an INT and a Decimal?

Tags: mysql

I have a field in a MySQL table called quantity.

I would like the quantity field to be able to store the following numbers: 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 and 1.

I currently have the field set as DECIMAL(2,2) as according to the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html).

It all works well, except for the 1, it always stores in the field as 0.99. Is there a way I can make this store as 1 instead of 0.99?

I have also tried passing in 1.0 and 1.00, but this also stores as 0.99.

Comment: If you want 3 significant digits why are you using a precision of 2?

Comment: Thanks @TangentiallyPerpendicular, that worked perfectly. Appreciate the help. I'd accidentally set the wrong amount of digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DECIMAL(2,2)` defines a two-digit number with two decimal places. It will only store two decimal digits. 0.99 is the closest it can get to 1.0

Use `DECIMAL(3,2)` - that's a three-digit number with two decimal places. That will allow space for the integer portion.